# Python dict with no attribute error in array

Tags: python, neural-network

I am using following to code to display array

```
net = NeuralNetwork(4, 28 * 28, [128, 64, 10])
print(net(1).w)
```

In NeuralNetwork file

```
  def __call__(self, counter):           
        return self.params[counter]
```

in init I am using

```
self.params     = [] 
np.random.seed(1)
        for i in range(len(neurons_per_layer)):
            w = np.random.randn(2,2)
            b = np.zeros([2, 1])
            self.params.append({"w" : w, "b" : b})

        return
```

However I am getting error

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'w'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `print(net(1).w)`, you are trying to access an attribute `w` of a `dict`, which `dict` does not have.

I think what you really want is `print(net(1)['w'])`

In summary, you are getting `'dict' object has no attribute 'w'` because you are trying to call an attribute from `dict`, in this case `w`, and `dicts` have no attribute called `w`, you want to retrieve the value on the `dict` for the **key** `w`.

Comment: I want to do print(net(1).w) , How can i modify my code to exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: `print(net(1)['w'])`

Comment: @El I do not want to do print(net(1)['w']), yes i understand my code does that but I want to exibit behavior as mentioned by me, How can I modify my code.

Comment: You mean, you want the thing that you put into the `self.params` in the first place, to *actually have* that `.w` attribute? Then you need to make it be something that does have that attribute, instead of using a `dict`. For example, by writing another class to represent it.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, Exactly, Karl its right, I missunderstood the question. What you want is a class

Comment: N.B. There are other ways (besides using a class) to implement such a hack E.g. overloading `__getattr__`. (I think `Collections.namedtuples` or `recordtype` might also work here?)

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary has a set of keys and a set of values.

Accessing a value through a key is `dict[key]`
Using `dict.key`you are trying to access an attribute from the class dict.

If you wish to exhibit the same behavior through the `instance.key` method, you will need to wrap you dictionary, or create a new class.

Else just use the python formula `dict[key]`.